# Index page is not coming / showing in laravel framework

Tags: laravel, installation

I am using Ubuntu 14.04LTS. Here is what i have done till now:

```
I have installed composer using curl,
move this composer.phar file to usr/local/bin directory
Created project laravel in my root folder i.e. var/www/html
Change the permission of app/storage folder.
Created the file name as laravel.conf like 000-default.conf in etc/apache2/site-avaliable directory.
edit that laravel.conf file from terminal and save that file.
disable 000-default.conf file and enable laravel.conf file.
restarted the apache2 service.
```

Here is my problem: now i am trying to run it from my localhost but it does not show index.php page of my project laravel.

Any help to sort this, will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel builds its own output based on your controllers, generally utilizing view files (blades) as templates. Unless you specifically tell it to in your controller, it will not return a static or dynamic index.php page. If this is your first Laravel project, I recommend reading up on how routing works at http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing .